# Create a sum with the Do function and modules

Tags: functions

I should define a function which sums up from `k=0` to `100`, with `x=1`; using the `Do` function and modules; without using the `Sum` function

I tried it this way:

```
blub[x_, p_]:=Do[blub=((-1)^k/x^k), {k, 1, p}]
blub[1, 100]
```

Problems:

1. I don't get any output
2. I don't get why I would need a module

I would be glad if someone could help me.

Thanks for the fast help,
Solution number 2 fits perfect for what I want.

Is there a posibility that I use a module inside the iterator?
So that I can use my function this way.

```
v=0;    
f[x_, n_]:=Do[v +=((-1)^n/x^n), {n, 1, n}]
f[1, 100]
v
```

Is there a posibility to make this work without changing one of the n's into another variable name (I`m aware that I double defined one variable)

Answer (score 7):

The following I hope will assist you:

```
b = 0;
blub[x_, p_] := Do[b += ((-1)^k/x^k), {k, 1, p}]
blub[1, 100]
b
```

or achieving the output:

```
f[x_, p_] := Module[{v = 0},
  Do[v += ((-1)^k/x^k), {k, 1, p}];
  v]
```

There are many ways to achieve this result, e.g.

```
s[x_, p_] := Sum[(-1)^k/x^k, {k, 1, p}]
r[x_, p_] := Total[(-1)^#/x^# & /@ Range[p]]
```